# Find Xpath for element in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to find a element in selenium with this XPATH. I get this in firefox web browser.

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a
```

HTML code
[image]

```
<a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiw7cbBv6LqAhVMAHIKHbbFCUYQFjAAegQIBxAB&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fgmail%2F&amp;usg=AOvVaw3mZ_qbD_gQyp_sqkjrwStn" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','','AOvVaw3mZ_qbD_gQyp_sqkjrwStn','','2ahUKEwiw7cbBv6LqAhVMAHIKHbbFCUYQFjAAegQIBxAB','','',event)" data-ctbtn="2" data-cthref="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiw7cbBv6LqAhVMAHIKHbbFCUYQFjAAegQIBxAB&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fgmail%2F&amp;usg=AOvVaw3mZ_qbD_gQyp_sqkjrwStn"><br><h3 class="LC20lb DKV0Md">Gmail by Google</h3><div class="TbwUpd NJjxre"><cite class="iUh30 bc tjvcx">www.google.com<span class="eipWBe"> › gmail</span></cite></div></a>
```

My Selenium Code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
```

But it's not working. Help me.

Comment: Can you expand the `<a>` tag and update the question with text based HTML of the element please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element to click on it, you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[@href='https://www.google.com/gmail/'] h3"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//h3[text()='Gmail by Google']"))).click();
  ```